# Oculus Gearvr (ovr_sdk_mobile_1.0.3 ) Select Target Configuration

Tags: android, build.gradle, oculus, gear-vr, oculus-runtime

I am importing the oculus ovr_sdk_mobile_1.0.3 mobile sdk in android studio, i am following [this link](https://developer3.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-studio-basics/) for importing the sdk, but i am not getting any target configuration in android studio.I won't get any error when i clean the project.

[image: not configuration]

Thanks!